# Change font size with ActionListener

Tags: java, fonts, actionlistener

I need to create a Listener that changes the font size when I click on a `JMenuItem`. However, I have different labels for different parts, so when I change the font size, it throws an error at me when the labels for the other parts of the program are called but not active. Basically I can't change all the fonts at once.

I've tried using if-statements but for some reason only the first one seems to work! The others give me a `nullPointerException`.

Here is my listener code thus far..

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;










public class financeFormula extends JFrame {



     private JMenu fileMenu;
       private JMenu textMenu;
       private JMenuItem exitItem;
       private JMenuItem fontSize;
       private JMenuItem help;
       private JPanel presentValuePanel;  
       private JPanel financeFinderPanel;// A panel container
       private JLabel principalMessage;  
       private JLabel yearlyRateMessage;
       private JLabel termYearMessage;
       private JPanel simpleInterestPanel;
       private JPanel doublingTimePanel;
       private JPanel compoundInterestPanel;
       private JLabel NONEMessage;
       private JLabel imageLabel;
       private JLabel label;// A message to display
       private JMenuBar menuBar;
       private JTextField principalText; // To hold user input
       private JButton calcButton;       // Performs calculation

       private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;  // Window width
       private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600; // Window height
       private JTextField yearlyRateText;
       private JTextField termYearText;
       DecimalFormat dc =new DecimalFormat("####0.00"); //formater 
       private JComboBox financeBox; 
       double principal = 400.0;
       double yearlyRate = .04;
       double termYears = 4.0;


       private String[] financeFormulas = { "NONE", "Present value", "Simple interest",
             "Doubling time", "Compound interest", "Decaf"};


       //financeFormulaClass financeFormula = new financeFormulaClass(principal, yearlyRate, termYears);

       /**
        *  Constructor
        */



       public financeFormula()
       {
          // Call the JFrame constructor.
          super("Finance Class");

          // Set the size of the window.
          setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

          // Specify what happens when the close
          // button is clicked.
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          // Build the panel and add it to the frame.
          financeFinderPanel();
          setLayout(new BorderLayout());

          //buildPanel();

          menuBar = new JMenuBar();
          //buildFileMenu();
          buildTextMenu();
          //menuBar.add(fileMenu);
          menuBar.add(textMenu);
          setJMenuBar(menuBar);

          // Add the panel to the frame's content pane.
          add(financeFinderPanel);
          //add(panel);

          // Display the window.
          setVisible(true);
       }

       private void financeFinderPanel()
       {
          // Create a panel to hold the combo box.


          financeFinderPanel = new JPanel();

          //create label
          label = new JLabel("Pick your formula");
          //ImageIcon funnyImage = new ImageIcon("funny.gif");
          //imageLabel = new JLabel();
          //imageLabel.setLocation(50, 55);

          label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
          // Create the combo box
          financeBox = new JComboBox(financeFormulas);
          //imageLabel.setIcon(funnyImage);
          // Register an action listener.
          financeBox.addActionListener(new financeBoxListener());
          exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");   
          exitItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);

          // Add the combo box to the panel.
          financeFinderPanel.add(financeBox);
          financeFinderPanel.add(label);
         // financeFinderPanel.add(imageLabel);


       }


       private void buildMenuBar()
       {
          // Create the menu bar.
          menuBar = new JMenuBar();

          // Create the file and text menus.
          //buildFileMenu();
          buildTextMenu();

          // Add the file and text menus to the menu bar.
          //menuBar.add(fileMenu);
          menuBar.add(textMenu);

          // Set the window's menu bar.
          setJMenuBar(menuBar);
       }



       public void buildTextMenu(){

           fontSize = new JMenuItem("Large font");
           fontSize.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_2);
           fontSize.addActionListener(new FontListener());
           textMenu = new JMenu("Text");
           textMenu.add(fontSize);



       }

       private void presentValuePanel()
       {
          // Create the label, text field, and button components.
          principalMessage = new JLabel("principal");
          principalText = new JTextField(10);
          yearlyRateMessage = new JLabel("Yearly Rate");
          yearlyRateText = new JTextField(10);
          termYearMessage = new JLabel("Term Year");
          termYearText = new JTextField(10);
          calcButton = new JButton("Calc Present Value");
          //fontButton = new JButton("Enlarge Font");

          // Add an action listener to the button.
          //calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

          //calcButton.addActionListener(new financeFormListener());
          //fontButton.addActionListener(new FontListener());
          // Create a panel to hold the components.
          presentValuePanel = new JPanel();

          // Add the label, text field, and button to the panel.
          presentValuePanel.add(principalMessage);
          presentValuePanel.add(principalText);
          presentValuePanel.add(yearlyRateMessage);
          presentValuePanel.add(yearlyRateText);
          presentValuePanel.add(termYearMessage);
          presentValuePanel.add(termYearText);
          presentValuePanel.add(calcButton);
          //presentValuePanel.add(fontButton);
       }

          private void simpleInterestPanel(){

                  principalMessage = new JLabel("principal");
                  principalText = new JTextField(10);
                  yearlyRateMessage = new JLabel("Yearly Rate");
                  yearlyRateText = new JTextField(10);
                  termYearMessage = new JLabel("Term Year");
                  termYearText = new JTextField(10);
                  calcButton = new JButton("Calc Simple Interest");

                  simpleInterestPanel = new JPanel();
               //   calcButton.addActionListener(new financeFormListener());

                  simpleInterestPanel.add(principalMessage);
                  simpleInterestPanel.add(principalText);
                  simpleInterestPanel.add(yearlyRateMessage);
                  simpleInterestPanel.add(yearlyRateText);
                  simpleInterestPanel.add(termYearMessage);
                  simpleInterestPanel.add(termYearText);
                  simpleInterestPanel.add(calcButton);



           }




       private class financeBoxListener implements ActionListener
       {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {

              String selection = (String) financeBox.getSelectedItem();
              if(selection.equals("Present value")){
                  //financeFinderPanel.removeAll();
                  presentValuePanel();
                  add(presentValuePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                  financeFinderPanel.removeAll();
                  pack();

              }



             else if(selection.equals("Simple interest")){

                 simpleInterestPanel();
                 add(simpleInterestPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                 financeFinderPanel.removeAll();
                 pack();                      
              }

          }
       }


              private class FontListener implements ActionListener{

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

                        if(presentValuePanel.isEnabled() && actionCommand.equals("Large font")){
                            principalMessage.setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
                        }
                        else if(simpleInterestPanel.isEnabled() && actionCommand.equals("Large font")){
                            principalMessage.setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
                        }


                    }
                 }


       static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        new financeFormula();

    }

}
```

NOTE: For some reason the Button enlarge font is still showing..That is not what I am asking for I am asking when I change different formulas and click the JMenuItem Large font it only works for present Value and not simple Interest..

Comment: Your question involves problems with the inter-relatedness of your code causing errors, even a NPE. I don't know how we're going to be able to guess what could be wrong with your program structure based on your description and small snippet of code, which means that you're going to want to post more code and tell us more. No, we don't want to see your entire program, but it would help if you could create a **small** (small enough to post as an edit to your question and not in a link) compiilable and runnable program that demonstrates your error directly for us, a [mcve].

Comment: Ok I made a small program that does what I am asking...When you click present value and then change the font with the JMenuItem it works but when you do it with simple interest it does not...Also please ignore the JButton "enlarge font" Idk why it is still appearing.

Comment: You have more than one JLabel object being put into the principalMessage variable, and what matters to the JVM is the object being used, not the variable. So your ActionListener is changing the Font on the object that it holds a reference to only. You should make your program more simple and not use the same variable for more than one object.

Comment: Changed them all and still didn't work...Not sure whats up.

Comment: Please post your latest code attempt.

Comment: Hey Hover, my latest was the code I sent you...

Comment: Hey, first please look at my answer.

Comment: Right so it's a null pointer exception...I get that just not sure what to change that doesn't make sense because my presentValuePanel, and simpleInterestPanel are both individual panels. Also one of them always work but not the other in an if else if statement. Anywho, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not telling us the most important part of your problem -- you're getting a NullPointerException. Again this is critical information that is key to knowing what's wrong and solving it, and should not be left out of your current or future questions.

The key to solving NPE's is to find the line that's throwing it, and then check it carefully for variables that are null. Then look back into your code to find out why and to correct it. Your NPE is being thrown here:

```
if(presentValuePanel.isEnabled() && actionCommand.equals("Large font")){
```

and is due to the presentValuePanel variable being null (since when simple interest is selected, the simpleInterestPanel is created but the presentValuePanel is not) and then your trying to call a method off of this null variable -- not allowed.

The solution is to not allow this to happen, to not allow methods to be called on null variables. One option is to create all your JPanels on program initialization, and this will be a valid option if your program is wired to be able to change to a different formula, something I think the future program will be doing. So this is OK. Otherwise another option is to check for null before calling the code. For instance, see changes to program:

```
public class financeFormula extends JFrame {
    public static final String LARGE_FONT = "Large Font"; // !!  constant

    //  ....

    public void buildTextMenu() {
        fontSize = new JMenuItem(LARGE_FONT); // !!  Use constant
        fontSize.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_2);
        fontSize.addActionListener(new FontListener());
        textMenu = new JMenu("Text");
        textMenu.add(fontSize);
    }

    // ....

    private class FontListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // !! block change
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            if (actionCommand.equals(LARGE_FONT)) { // !!  check for Large Font, and if pressed set the Fonts
                if (presentValuePanel != null && presentValuePanel.isEnabled()) {  // Check for null!
                    principalMessage.setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
                } else if (simpleInterestPanel != null && simpleInterestPanel.isEnabled()) {  // Check for null!
                    principalMessage.setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
                }
            }
            // !! block change
        }
    }
```

Note when using Strings for equality checks, always use a String constant to avoid trivial but hard to debug spelling or capitalization mistakes.

For more on NullPointerExceptions, please read: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)